# IOS - Como fazer app mandar notificações estando fechado?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mobile, xcode

Gostaria de saber como posso executar uma ação, como de uma notificação por exemplo, com o app estando fechado.

Como quando você não está utilizando o telefone e recebe uma notificação de mensagem do Facebook ou de um jogo por ex.

Quero fazer um app que depende deste recurso. toda dica é válida pessoal, Abraço!

Comment: Muito Obrigado Douglas, pelo que vi, tenho de conseguir um dispositivo, pois não consigo fazer pela maquina virtual, vou correr atras disto, caso eu consiga ou não, aviso aqui no futuro. Abraço!